# elasticsearch BindTransportException at startup

Tags: search, elasticsearch, pyes

This is the exception I'm getting starting up elasticsearch:

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/03/21 00:43:42 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/21 00:43:42 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/21 00:43:45 | {0.19.4}: Startup Failed ...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/21 00:43:45 | - BindTransportException[Failed to bind to [9300]]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/21 00:43:45 |       ChannelException[Failed to bind to: /192.168.0.1:9300]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/21 00:43:45 |               BindException[Cannot assign requested address]
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/03/21 00:43:47 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Does anybody have a clue about what could cause the issue?

Comment: you probably have another instance already running or some other running process using the same port

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out what process is using that port, for example on OS X, using the Network Utility Portscan tab for port 9300.
This will give you something like this:

```
Open TCP Port:  9300        vrace
```

You can use this line to get the processes that are listeningL

```
lsof -i | grep LISTEN
```

This will return something like this:

```
java      12345 niranjan  123u  IPv6 0x1ab123c45d67890f      0t0  TCP localhost:vrace (LISTEN)
```

You can use

```
ps aux | grep 12345
```

to see what that process is. You can then decide to kill that process using

```
sudo kill -9 12345
```

and voila your original app will work again.

Linux might be slightly different but the logic is the same: do a portscan on localhost, see what app is using port 9300, then whack it.